# Creating a scoresheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I am trying to automate the weekly process of score sheets for our local club. We have three worksheets:

```
1 worksheet for main print form,  
1 worksheet with all teams and players names, and  
1 sheet with all the scheduling detail (identified by a GameID).
```

I have it automated so that if I select a `GameID` from a drop-down list on the print form it will put in details for the corresponding game (venue, time, date, teams).

What I would like it to do there is, from the team names that are selected for that game, to populate the list of players names into cells on the print form so they can sign off who played.  I figured I need to do one formula and cut/paste it for the 7-10 spots in each team.

Is this going to be possible in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some assumptions.

The sheet with all teams and players looks of this nature:
[image: SO19603985 first example]

where the content of the outlined box is a range named `players`. I have assumed you do not need signatures for 'opponents' or that `7-10 spots` is the total for both sides in any one game.

The scheduling sheet (I've called `Schedule`) is for me needed only for testing purposes: 
[image: SO19603985 second example]

The main print form sheet (I’ve called `print`) looks vaguely like so:
[image: SO19603985 third example]

The table at the top again is for testing purposes. I would anticipate only the row showing validation would be required.

The formulae in B10:B19 are:

```
 =VLOOKUP($A$2,players,ROW()-8,0)
```

in B10 copied down. Note that if placed in a different row the `-8` would need adjusting.

Comment: Thanks for going out of your way pnuts

sheet 1<img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img132/6550/qink.png">
sheet 2<img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img401/5783/vhrf.png">
sheet 3 <img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img849/4584/pc61.png">

Comment: Not at all mate.  I really appreciate the time and effort taken but thought i could post images as my explanation wasn't the best.  Working on what you have given me in above response to adapt and hopefully it can come together.

Comment: + 1 For going out of the way to explain it :)

Comment: That's ok. We all go through this stage :)